# Log4j error during deploing web application

Tags: glassfish, log4j

I have a problem, I try to deploy my web project in glasfish 3.1.2, it is works fine but throws  the following error, please help me to understand what is the problem

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR log4j called after unloading, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload.
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:199)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:229)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor47.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES system property to false.

```
<jvm-options>
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFEREN‌​CES=false
</jvm-options>
```

This can be found in the domain.xml file in Glassfish (glassfish/domains/domain1/config)

Comment: Thanks Ben for answer but I have other problem

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFEREN‌​CES=false

Comment: I append -D the parameter and glassfish start, but I have the same problem

Comment: Are you using a parser such as xerces.jar?

Comment: Hmm Ok will have another look. Did you say it all works though?

Comment: <jvm-options>-org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFEREN‌​CES=false</jvm-options> forgot the minus

Answer (score 0):

I worked for me.
`<jvm-options>
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFEREN‌​CES=false
</jvm-options>`
And it should be between  and .
you can find domain.xml in (*{glassfish domains folder}/glassfish/domains/domain1 /config*).
I used log4j-1.2.17 and GlassFish Server 3.1